# Find if JSON file contains string and return airport name

Tags: php, json

I have a rather large JSON file with a complete list of Airports and their respective information (46000 lines total).

I want to be able to check if the JSON file contains an ICAO and then return in a variable the Airport Name.

Ideally something like this (just as an example)

```
if ($jsonFile contains $icao) {

    $airportName = airport_name of $icao;

} else {
    echo 'Sorry, that ICAO could not be found';
}
```

#### JSON extract:

```
[
{
    "complete_location": "Anaa, Tuamotus, French Polynesia",
    "iata_code": "AAA",
    "city": "Anaa",
    "icao_code": "NTGA",
    "country": " French Polynesia",
    "airport_name": "Anaa Airport"
},
{
    "complete_location": "Arrabury, Queensland, Australia",
    "iata_code": "AAB",
    "city": "Arrabury",
    "icao_code": "YARY",
    "country": " Australia",
    "airport_name": "Arrabury Airport"
},
{
    "complete_location": "El Arish, Egypt",
    "iata_code": "AAC",
    "city": "El Arish",
    "icao_code": "HEAR",
    "country": " Egypt",
    "airport_name": "El Arish International Airport"
},
```

### Example:

If I entered the ICAO `YARY` I would get returned the airport name `Arrabury Airport`

### Personal attempts:

I have so far managed to print all the json data in a webpage as such:

[image: JSON file outputted]

#### Using the following code:

```
<?php
    // The JSON file location
    $JSONdatas = file_get_contents('icao/datas/city_airport_codes.json');
    $ARRAYdatas = json_decode($JSONdatas);

?>

<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="200">IATA Codes</th>
                    <th width="200">ICAO Codes</th>
                    <th width="200">Airport Names</th>
                    <th>Locations</th>
                    <th width="150">Cities</th>
                    <th width="150">Countries</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $rows = '';
                    foreach($ARRAYdatas as $key => $airport)
                    {
                        $rows .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$airport->iata_code.'</td>
                            <td>'.$airport->icao_code.'</td>
                            <td>'.$airport->airport_name.'</td>
                            <td>'.$airport->complete_location.'</td>
                            <td>'.$airport->city.'</td>
                            <td>'.$airport->country.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        ';
                    }
                    echo $rows;
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```php
$condition = 'YARY';
$airports = array_filter($ARRAYdatas, function($item) use(&$condition) {
    return isset($item->icao_code) && $item->icao_code == $condition; 
});

$airport = array_pop($airports);
$airportName = $airport ? $airport->airport_name : '';
```

There may be a more elegant or faster solution, but I think this way it's really easy to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some performance gains, it may be a good call to cache the `json_decode()` output in native PHP format and include that file instead. Presuming you are including the .json file on each page load. (Use `var_export()` to dump the data into a PHP-readable format.)

Comment: This sounds like a useful change.  Are you able to put it in context?  Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably want to have a separate parser script, where you get the contents of the JSON file and parse it into an array (as you now do in the beginning of your script). The parser would save the array into a file; `file_put_contents()` etc. (Be sure to prefix the array data from `var_export` with a variable name and the PHP open tag.) Then, in your main file, in place of interpreting the JSON every time, you'd simply include the file with the ready-parsed PHP array. You would only run the JSON parser once, whenever your data is updated. Does that provide context enough?

Comment: For ease of lookups, it'd also be useful to loop over the JSON data and turn it into an associative array using the airport codes as the array keys. Then all you'd need to do is `if (isset($airports[$icao_code])) { echo $airports[$icao_code]['airport_name']; }` or so, saving you from filtering or iterating through the whole array on each query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with callbacks, you can also use:

```
function isICAO($Icao = NULL, $_json = array())
{
    array_walk($_json, function($item, $key) use($Icao){
        if($item->icao_code == $Icao) { echo $item->airport_name; }
    });
}
// Print Airport name if icao_code is found. Else nothing.
echo isICAO("NTGA", $_json);
```

Old way before callbacks

```
<?php
function isICAO($Icao = NULL, $_json = array())
{
    foreach ($_json as $key => $item)
    {
        if($item->icao_code == $Icao) 
        {
            return $item->airport_name;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if($Airport = isICAO("NTGA", $_json))
{
    echo $Airport;
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, that ICAO could not be found";
}
?>
```

Javascript code:

```
var json = [
    {
        "complete_location": "Anaa, Tuamotus, French Polynesia",
        "iata_code": "AAA",
        "city": "Anaa",
        "icao_code": "NTGA",
        "country": " French Polynesia",
        "airport_name": "Anaa Airport"
    },
    {
        "complete_location": "Arrabury, Queensland, Australia",
        "iata_code": "AAB",
        "city": "Arrabury",
        "icao_code": "YARY",
        "country": " Australia",
        "airport_name": "Arrabury Airport"
    },
    {
        "complete_location": "El Arish, Egypt",
        "iata_code": "AAC",
        "city": "El Arish",
        "icao_code": "HEAR",
        "country": " Egypt",
        "airport_name": "El Arish International Airport"
    }
];

function isICAO(Icao)
{
    var result = [];
    json.map(function(value, index) {
        if(value.icao_code == Icao) { result.push(value); }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(isICAO('HEAR'));

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what I needed.  I was looking for something to return the airport name of the ICAO.